# How to fill a MainWindow with one of two UserControls using a local variable

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm not new to WPF or C# but I am new to MVVM and the ViewModel situation.

I've been going through the MVVM and binding basics for what I need to accomplish but I'm still
being tripped up with the xaml specifics.

My end goal is to create one blank MainWindow.xaml view being populated with one of two UserControl.xaml views.

I have 2 simplistic UserControl Views: MainView.xaml and OptionalView.xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestViewSwap.MainView"
         ...>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Main View" />
</Grid>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestViewSwap.OptionalView"
         ...>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Optional View" />
</Grid>
```

And a MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestViewSwap.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Window>
```

I know that CurrentView needs to be set in code behind to either OptionalView or MainView
dependent upon whatever I choose, but what I don't know yet is... what type CurrentView
needs to be or what code behind file it needs to be in?

Comment: Sleff - I am trying to solve the exact same issue and have some headstart. Can you ping me at my email address - we can collaborate and post and answer back for the benefit of others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CurrentView should be a property om your MainWindowViewModel or whatever class that is your Datacontext on Window.xaml. For each view you define a data template. The data template can contain the view or point to a user control. Assign the CurrentView to a view model to switch view. Here is some code:

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
  object currentView;

  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    CurrentView = new OptionalView();
    SwitchViewCommand = new RelayCommand(SwitchView);
  }

  public object CurrentView
  {
    get { return this.currentView; }
    set 
    { 
      this.currentView = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
    }
  }

  public RelayCommand SwitchViewCommand { get; set; }

  void SwitchView()
  {
    if (CurrentView is OptionalView)
      CurrentView = new SettingsView();
    else
      CurrentView = new OptionalView();
  }
}

public class OptionalView { }

public partial class SettingsView { }
```

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfLab.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfLab.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfLab.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OptionalView}">
        <Border Background="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SettingsView}">
        <views:SettingsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding SwitchViewCommand}"
            Content="SwitchView" />
</Grid>
```

**Settings View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfLab.Views.SettingsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Border Background="Green" />
```

Comment: Per - Understand what you are suggesting - having CurrentView as a public property is obviously necessary - but how do you bind either usercontrol through that property (meaning if the property in the MainWindowViewModel is set as value = OptionalView) - then how do you translate that in the Mainwindow.xaml and render the Optional View user control. Assumption here is that the usercontrols do not have any ViewModels and are simple usercontrols (having just plain XAML code)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Even if you don't need a separate view model fore each view it's an easy way for rendering different views.

Comment: Thanks Per, I had vacillated between separate view model(s) for each view and not, so I have no preference at the moment, nor specific need for it from an app requirement standpoint. I'll see what this does for me now.

Comment: I have seen both the examples - one with a viewmodel for each usercontrol (so it can be referenced) and one without. Here are the examples: http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx